# Calling External API from Spring Boot Web UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot WebMVC application (with Thymeleaf) that is moving away from a direct database connection in favor of API calls to another service. I am wondering what the best architecture would be for calling the API and displaying the results to the user. Would RestTemplate be better to put in the Service class, or the Controller class (especially when thinking about error handling)? Also, would WebClient be better over RestTemplate even though it isn't using WebFlux?

Here is currently what I am thinking:

Entity:

```
public class Entity {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    ...
}
```

Service:

```
public class EntityService {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public List<Entity> getAllEntities() {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("https://localhost.com:8081/entities", Entity.class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class EntityController {
    @Autowired
    private EntityService entityService;

    @GetMapping("/entities")
    public String getAllEntities(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(entityList, entityService.getAllEntities())
        return "entity"
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- entity.html -->

<head>
...
</head>
<body>    
    <div th:each="entity : #{entityList}">
        <label th:text="${entity.id}"/>
        <label th:text="${entity.name}"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It depends" is the answer to all your questions :)

So to work out the answers, you need to think about your application, how big it's going to get and how you will keep it all under control as it matures. The things I'd consider are:

- How many upstream API calls will your app make? If there's only 1 and virtually no business logic, then a `Service` layer might just add noise, however if you start doing things other than just straight up displaying bean properties then the less code sitting in the `Controller` the clearer the app will be to the next person. I like to keep Controllers specific to the transport - eg HTTP or gRPC - and dealing with things like response codes, headers etc, so I generally move the `if`s off to a service layer.
- `RestTemplate` vs `WebClient` is usually a great distraction. If you are using traditional blocking Spring Boot, use `RestTemplate`, if you are using Reactive then use `WebClient`. It doesn't really matter that much from the application code perspective, it's usually not a huge job to replace one with the other if you've got the application architecture thought out.

Another thing - try avoid a `controller` package, a `service` package and a `model` package, group all this stuff together under the business context - in this case an `Entity`, but we all know there is going to be a service, controller, models etc etc.

You really don't want to have 300 controller classes in the `controller` package, best they are grouped together in a way that would make sense to the users or the product owner of an app..

My final bit of advice would be to not be afraid to change as the app gets bigger. Ensure your tests are reliable enough that you can refactor the app as you go. Things like replacing `RestTemplate` with something else, changing the app structure and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is making many calls (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and manipulating data, so I think using RestTemplate and putting the exception handling in a `Service` layer makes sense for my app.The only thing I'm concerned about is giving enough information about errors when they happen. If a Service method returns a list of objects (like in my original example) but the API throws an error, how can I send an error message about what went wrong to the user? For example, if the API returns a 503 error, I would want to display a message saying there is a problem with the service.

Comment: yeah, that's always a hassle. Spring Boot has a few options for exception handling, with an API I typically end up with ControllerAdvice mapping exceptions to a error response from the controller. So you'd throw a ServiceUnavailableException from the service layer. IIRC There's a similar exception handling with ModelAndView / UI. exception is mapped  to a 500 error and friendly error page on the UI.